# What is the Chinese word for 'programmer'?

Tags: translation, word-requests

I know that a couple of variation of "coding" or programming are 编程, or 写代码. How would I refer to that person who does the coding/programming? Is it 编程家? or is there a more colloquial way of saying it?

Comment: Dialect note: the Taiwanese term for programmers is usually `軟體工程師`. But a more colloquial way is referring to someone as `寫程式的`, i.e. `周小姐是寫程式的`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`编程家` sounds weird. You can say:

```
程序员
程序猿 (for male)
程序媛 (for female)
编程人员
码农 (junior programmer without future, often used for self-mockery)
挨踢(IT)民工 (similar to 码农)
```

Comment: haha I like 程序猿, Homo programmatis under the class of homo http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Sky6t/program-ape

Comment: Would `程序猿` be the equivalent of `code monkey`, the somewhat derogatory English term?

Comment: @Cocowalla Yes, I think so. It's `code monkey`.

Answer (score 7):

程序员 is widely used in China as “programmer”。

Answer (score 5):

软件工程师（軟件工程師） should be a good one.

Comment: This is what I normally say (or the Taiwanese variant 軟體工程師)

Comment: This means 'software engineer', not 'programmer'.

Comment: Isn't this "software engineer", not "programmer"?

Answer (score 3):

程序员 is the widely used word. In most company, including the one I'm currently working in, people use 程序 to call 程序员, some kinda in short. 主程: LP/ Chief Programmer.
A funny version is 程序猿[code monkey]. 猿(yuan2) is gorilla.
Also, 码农[a programmer who gets low salary],程序媛[female code monkey](媛 means girl).

Comment: Sean,  I've heard that 码农 isn't that often used/is 网络语。 Do you think I should ever use it when speaking as a joke? 

Like 
我以后想当一个码农。

Comment: You can but it sounds weird. We often call ourselves(who are already coders) 码农 (as a joke of course). See this self sarcasm: 人家敲代码几年都成男神高富帅了，我特么还是一码农/屌丝程序猿。(And I am the 屌丝程序猿 :P)

Comment: Oh awesome - so, I could probably use it if I was a computer science student as well though/considered myself a programmer

Answer (score 2):

you can say '程序员'

EG：
程序员总是有着相同的风格
Programmer alway has same style of wear.

Answer (score 1):

I've also heard 程序设计师 (设计师 = designer, architect).

Answer (score 0):

You can use 程序员, 程序师, or 程序设计师 (设计师 means architect/designer and 程序 means a program).